# How to use a Unity as a XAML control in an existing UWP Project?

Tags: c#, xaml, unity-game-engine, uwp

We have a UWP project in which we want to render 3d content using Unity.

Unity can build to a UWP project, which renders the 3d content on swapchainpanels in a XAML control. So now we want to use this in our own UWP project.

So I build a Unity UWP project, then tried to copy the content of the generated project to a new project in our solution so I can use it. But when trying to add all the referenced dlls, Visual Studio says that "A reference to ... could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."
(I'm trying to add all the dlls from the "Players" folder)

I'm at a loss as to what I have to do to get this working, I'm familiar with developing in Unity, but not lower level stuff like this. Any help is much appreciated. Let me know If you need any more info.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Unity 2017.3.1

Comment: It's similar, but the answer there isn't usefull to me, as I can't use the project Unity generates, but rather use the content instead in an existing project. As I had specified in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just copy the Unity project into another solution. Unity projects require the presence of the engine, alongside it's libraries to compile. You can't reference Unity libraries from other projects either.

You should instead build the Unity project and use it directly from your XAML control(s).

Comment: Do you mean I should just use the generated project? Because I can't do that, the unity part is just a small part we need it in another big UWP project. Are you saying there's no way to move the Unity content from the generated project to another project?

Comment: You can't use Unity libraries outside of a Unity proyect